# Error page not shown in some cases in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, error-handling

I have this function in `global.php` for errors

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception); 
}); 
App::missing(function(Exception $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});

App::error(function(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

This in `routes.php`

```
App::error(function(Exception $e) {
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);  
});
```

And this in controller

```
$user = User::where('id', $userId)->first();
if (!$user) {
        App::missing(404);
}
```

If I go to url like: http://example.com/user/13432 and the user with ID 13432 doesn't exist I've got 404 page.

But if I go to url like: http://example.com/user/fdsfsdfsd I've got nothing .. is staying same page. Why I don't get 404 page?

Comment: What's your route for the user page?

Comment: Post your `routes.php`, please.

Comment: `Route::get ('/user/{userId}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@users', 'before' => 'admin']);` Is it because is expecting ID eg. int?

Comment: The goal is to make 404 for all wrong urls and pages..

Comment: Can you explain what "is staying same page." means?

Comment: If I'm on page `http://example.com/user/32` where user with id=32 exist and I manually add something after 32: `http://example.com/user/32dsgfdsfds` just refreshing the page and nothing happen. If I try to open url which doesn't exist at all: `http://example.com/daslkfdkjs` I've got `Error in exception handler.` instead of 404

Comment: Check your error log stored in app/storage/logs. `Error in exception handler.` might be caused by many things. Also you can `dd($userId)` in your controller right before this line `$user = User::where('id', $userId)->first();` and post your result. :)

Comment: It's showing undefined variable...on view which clearly doesn't exist.. but why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139466/discussion-between-ivanka-todorova-and-vls).

Comment: @VLS Since I don't think you are going back into the chat room. What you posted was exactly the way you can achieve what you are after. Glad you solved it!

Comment: @IvankaTodorova, thanks. Sorry I was off.. You can post the solution as an answer since is helped me and resolved my issue.